# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess for .Net 3.5

Tags: odp.net, odp.net-managed

The question is:

Is there a library with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess for .NET 3.5?

Currently application uses.NET 4.0 but I must crate opportunity to use application on .NET 3.5 with independent Oracle library.

Answer (score 3):

The fully managed driver, which uses the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` namespace, is only available for .NET 4.0, as can be read in the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/InstallSystemRequirements.htm#ODPNT149).

If you need to support .NET 3.5 you have to either use the unmanaged driver (`Oracle.DataAccess` namespace) or a third party driver like [dotConnect for Oracle](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/).